# JavaFX - File explorer doesn't open in another full-screen stage

Tags: java, file, user-interface, javafx

I'm actually beginning to learn JavaFX and I've got a problem!

I have a full-screen `Stage` and I would like, when I click on a button, to open a new stage over the primary stage! 
But actually, my second stage directly spawns in my desktop.

I don't know where I failed or what I forgot. If someone can help me or another people with the same problem, thank you.

Sorry I comment in french :/

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {         
    //Chargement de l'image 
    Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("res/spaceB.gif"));  
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 

    //Création du bouton
    Button b = new Button();
    // Rajout de l'image sur le boutton
    b.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image((new FileInputStream("res/play.png")))));
    //Reduuit le boutton qu'a l'image
    b.setFont(new Font(0));
    //Taille boutton
    b.setLayoutX(850);
    b.setLayoutY(450);


    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        //        FileChooserExample f = new FileChooserExample();
        Stage s2 = new Stage();

        Button choise = new Button("Choisir son fichier");
        choise.setLayoutX(8);
        choise.setLayoutY(45);

        choise.setOnAction(e2 -> {

            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("doc"));
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(s2);
            if(selectedFile != null) {
                nom = selectedFile.getName();
            }
        });


        Group g2 = new Group(choise);
        Scene sc2 = new Scene(g2,600,500);
        //Ajout nom et raccord de la scene au stage
        s2.setTitle("File recorder ");  
        s2.setScene(sc2);
        s2.show(); 
    });     
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */     

    //Je possitionne l'image en 0/0
    imageView.setX(0); 
    imageView.setY(0); 

    //Me permet d'avoir l'image en plein ecran (marche que pour l'IUT)
    //Pas encore trouvé pour faire un fullscreen d'une imageview
    imageView.setFitHeight(1950); 
    imageView.setFitWidth(1950); 

    //Garde le ratio de l'image et évite un gros zoom
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);  

    //Creating a Group object  
    Group root = new Group(imageView, b);   
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);  


    //Ajout nom et raccord de la scene au stage
    stage.setTitle("Bienvenue à SPACE-DUCK");  
    stage.setScene(scene);

    //Met en plein écran le GIF et affiche
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.setResizable(true);
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: By definition fullscreen means only a single "window" is rendered...

Comment: @fabian Then how is it possible to display message boxes into games?

Comment: You'd need to make the dialog part of the scene. `FileChooser` unfortunately is one of the dialogs that do not extend `Dialog` and therefore there's no way of extracting a `dialogPane`. The os functionality is used to display that dialog. Unfortunately this means you have to implement this functionality yourself (unless there's a third party api somewhere). Not too difficult a task but it'll certainly take time...

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour Nekolas,

Your case is not a bug. To make your stage appear over the primary stage, you have to create a dependance between those two instances : `stage` has to be the **owner** of `s2`. You can make it by placing the command :

```
s2.initOwner(stage);
```

before the command `s2.show()`.
I've tested your code with random pictures and it works:

---

[image: Interface principale avec le bouton PLAY au milieu]
**Main interface with a little PLAY button in the middle**

---

[image: Appui sur le bouton PLAY]
**Button PLAY pressed**

---

J'espère que ça t'aidera :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup de ton aide !

Comment: Pas de souci :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bug.
Try this:

Add

```
s2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Replace

```
stage.setFullScreen(true); -> stage.setMaximized(true);
```